# EF Linq to get latest version of row in table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table that contains details about an item and versions, like so:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+
| BookId | VersionId | InstanceId |         TitleText          |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+
|      1 |         1 |          1 | A great book!              |
|      1 |         2 |          2 | Great Book, v2!            |
|      2 |         1 |          3 | Cooking for Dummies        |
|      3 |         1 |          4 | Networks for Dummies       |
|      2 |         2 |          5 | Cooking for Smarter People |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+
```

I'm trying to query all the rows that are the latest (highest) VersionId for the BookId.  So my desired result set would look like:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+
| BookId | VersionId | InstanceId |         TitleText          |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+
|      1 |         2 |          2 | Great Book, v2!            |
|      3 |         1 |          4 | Networks for Dummies       |
|      2 |         2 |          5 | Cooking for Smarter People |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+
```

The SQL I'm running to get this is:

```
select t1.* from Books t1
left outer join Books t2
on (t1.BookId = t2.BookId and t1.VersionId < t2.VersionId)
where t2.BookId is null
```

But after a bit of googling I cannot figure out how to turn this into a linq query (using the extension method sytax).  The examples I'm seeing tend to join two different tables and I'm just not figuring out how to mold it to what I need.

Found this, and it seems to be close to what I'm looking for but what do I do for Foo and Bar being the same table?

```
Foo.GroupJoin(
          Bar, 
          foo => foo.Foo_Id,
          bar => bar.Foo_Id,
          (x,y) => new { Foo = x, Bars = y })
    .SelectMany(
          x => x.Bars.DefaultIfEmpty(),
          (x,y) => new { Foo=x.Foo, Bar=y});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to translate your anti-join to a where-not-exists:

```
select t1.*
from Books t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from Books t2
    where t2.BookId = t1.BookId and t2.VersionId > t1.VersionId
)
```

Which should translate to LINQ as:

```
AllBooks.Where(t1 => 
    !AllBooks.Any(t2 => t1.BookId == t2.BookId && t2.VersionId > t1.VersionId))
```

Comment: Very nice solution, both the SQL and LINQ. Maybe it's a common pattern, but I've never seen it before, and usually I have to struggle with nested selects and MAX(), etc. It's good to know for the future

Comment: The SQL is definitely a common pattern. I like @MarcinJuraszek 's answer better for LINQ though as it feels more, well, LINQ-y.

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect to get me past my hurdle.

Answer (score 3):

How about using grouping instead?

```
from x in myTable
group x by x.BookId into g
select g.OrderByDescending(y => y.VersionId).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: That's certainly simpler. Can EF actually translate that? And if so I'm curious the SQL it generates.

Comment: I would expect it to use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @lc. It generates this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hRvUg41m  I replaced the columns selects with *, since I'm running it on a company DB - but the rest is what's generated

Comment: Now that I'm thinking of it - this actually selects 1 row for each VersionId, so with 100 books and 3 versions, it would return 3 rows, not 100. It should be `group x by x.BookId` and then `OrderByDescending(g => g.VersionId)`

Comment: Correct. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL I would combine JOIN and GROUP BY to find the latest version of each book:

```
SELECT 
    book.BookId, 
    book.VersionId, 
    book.InstanceId, 
    book.TitleText
FROM Book AS book
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
              book.BookId,
              MAX(book.VersionId) AS MaxVersion
            FROM Book AS book
            GROUP BY book.BookId) AS grp
  ON book.BookId = grp.BookId AND book.VersionId = grp.MaxVersion
```

Following LINQ query will be translated by Entity Framework into exactly the same:

```
from book in Books
join latest in
    from book in Books
    group book.VersionId by book.BookId into grp
    select new { Id = grp.Key, Version = grp.Max() }
  on new { Id = book.BookId, Version = book.VersionId } equals latest
select book;
```